# Problem with rendering component when using window.location.pathname and window.location.hash with navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.location

I am having an issue trying to render an react component using an navigation bar. I have tried both ways with both Switch case and if-statement.

First way is using the window.location.hash which works and changes the url on click but I have to refresh the browser in order to see to render the right component, i.e. show the selected component.

The other way is to target window.location.pathname which writes the url in the desired way but instead of rendering the desired component, it renders my main page instead.

Here I will show the code.

**About.jsx(The version with Pathname is commented out and uses if-statement. Either one gives me the same problem):**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import AboutMe from './About/AboutMe';
import AboutMeNavigationBar from './About/AboutMeNav';
import Career from './About/Career';
import Education from './About/Education';
import Skills from './About/Skills';

export default function About(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("about-nav-bar")[0]);
    return(
        <div>
            <AboutMeNavigationBar />
            {selectSection()}
        </div>
    );
}

function selectSection(){
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    console.log(window.location);
    console.log(path);
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    switch (hash) {
        case '#skills':
            return <Skills />
        case '#career':
            return <Career />
        case '#education':
            return <Education />
        default:
            return <AboutMe />    
    }
    // if (path === "/about/skills") {
    //     console.log();
    //     return <Skills />
    // }
    // else if (path === "/about/career") {
    //     return <Career />
    // }
    // else if (path === "/about/education") {
    //     return <Education />
    // }
    // else return <AboutMe />
}
```

**AboutMeNav.jsx(with href=#....):**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../App';

export default function AboutNav(props){
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    return <Sections />
}

export function Sections(props){
    return(
            <ul className="about-nav-bar">
                <Section text="ABOUT ME" href="#aboutme"></Section>
                <Section text="SKILLS" href="#skills"></Section>
                <Section text="CAREER" href="#career"></Section>
                <Section text="EDUCATION" href="#education"></Section>
            </ul>
    );
}

export function Section(props){
    return(
        <li>
            <a href={props.href}>{props.text}</a>
        </li>
    );
}
```

**AboutMeNav.jsx(href="/about/aboutme" etc.):**

```
......
.........
export function Sections(props){
    return(
            <ul className="about-nav-bar">
                <Section text="ABOUT ME" href="/about/aboutme"></Section>
                <Section text="SKILLS" href="/about/skills"></Section>
                <Section text="CAREER" href="/about/career"></Section>
                <Section text="EDUCATION" href="/about/education"></Section>
            </ul>
    );
}
......
..........
```

Coming to scenario number two, it shows the right url in the browser but keeps redirecting me to the main page.
Will show the main **App.js** code since it strangely redirects according to that switch case:

```
import './App.css';
import NavigationBar from './Components/Navigationbar';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import About from './Components/About';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';

function App() {
  function switchPage(){
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
      case '/about':
        return( <About />);
      case '/contact':
        return( <Contact />);
      default:
        return(<Home />);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavigationBar className="Navbar" /> 
      
      <header className="App-header">
          {switchPage()}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is how my page looks like initially:
[image]

**My filestructure**:
[image]

Could someone please help me with these issues? Are there any solutions to my problems without using react-router?

All help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because change the URL will not trigger re-render the app. So you need to listen to the URL change events to update your components. I don't know which event to listen to for the pathname. But for the hash, you can try `hashchange`.

Example for Hash:

```
export default function App() {
  const [hash, setHash] = React.useState(window.location.hash);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      setHash((prev) => {
        const newHash = window.location.hash;
        if (prev !== newHash) {
          return newHash;
        }
        return prev;
      });
    };
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", handler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("hashchange", handler);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#hash1">hash 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#hash2">hash 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>Current hash: {hash}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Switch` and `Route`: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch, you don't have to use your own switch case ;)